# Issue with Date Filtering in Power BI Relationships

Tags: powerbi, filtering, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, fact

I'm encountering an issue with date filtering in Power BI, particularly regarding relationships between my fact table and dimension tables.

My fact table contains a date field, and I have two dimesion table, Both of my dimension tables also has a date field. I have successfully connected my fact table with this dimension table using the date field as the connection. However, when I apply a filter to the date in one table, it doesn't affect the data displayed in the other dimension table, even though they are connected by date.

The other dimesion table is filtering correctly however my other dimesion  table is not working so when I filter my visuals one is working but the other one is not. Pleaseeeee help. I circle in yellow my error thank you.

[image]

[image]

I've checked the relationship between the tables, and it seems to be set up correctly. I've also verified that both date fields are formatted as date data types. Despite this, the filter applied to the date in one table isn't propagating to the other table.

Answer (score 0):

In model view, please try to change the relationship filter to Both

[image]

This is because flow of direction in PowerBI matters a lot. so you can filter table GI with opportunity with date, but not the other way around. I also suggest using date from table Date, instead of GI